# JQuery - how to attach a method to the 2nd state in an event that has no states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, slidedown

I'm using the premade `.slideToggle` method in JQuery
I want to add an object to the `.slideDown` state of `.slideToggle`. ie) When I click a button I want to bind that object to the `.slideDown` event and 'close' it. However I obviously cannot just `.add` the object to `.slideToggle`. Is there a way to specifically target the `slideDown` state? Or do I have to utilize `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` if I want the privilege of specificity?

Obviously `.slideToggle` is another super easy JQuery "let's look like magic while we cache all the `if{`s and all the rest into one big variable".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to give up using `.slideToggle()` but you can still use the convenience of [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

```
$('#some-element').toggle(function() {
  // put slideDown here, along with anything else that should accompany it
}, function() {
  // put slideUp here, etc.
});
```

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was thinking. I'm still holding out for someone to chime in with a neat lil' trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do like this. It's not better than @Justin Ward's way. But it works

```
$("#some-element").slideToggle(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        // Do something (showing)
    } else {
        // Do something (not showing)
    }
});
```